# Runing NebulaGraph on Docker error: Failed to read the directory "/data/meta/nebula", No such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nebula-graph

I have 3 servers in 3 different datacenters with public IP stored in `.env` file:

```
TZ=UTS
USER=root
PASSWORD=passroot
SERVER1=154.13.92.23
SERVER2=154.13.92.24
SERVER3=154.13.92.25
```

Docker compose for running distribute nebula is :

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  metad:
    image: vesoft/nebula-metad:v3.5.0
    environment:
      USER: "${USER}"
      PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
      TZ:   "${TZ}"
    command:
      - --meta_server_addrs="${SERVER1}":9559,${SERVER2}":9559,${SERVER3}":9559
      - --local_ip=metad
      - --ws_ip=metad
      - --port=9559
      - --ws_http_port=19559
      - --data_path=/data/meta
      - --log_dir=/logs
      - --v=0
      - --minloglevel=0
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:9559:9559
      - 0.0.0.0:19559:19559
      - 0.0.0.0:19560:19560
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sf", "http://metad:19559/status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 20s
    volumes:
      - ./data/meta:/data/meta
      - ./logs/meta:/logs

  storaged:
    image: vesoft/nebula-storaged:v3.5.0
    environment:
      USER: "${USER}"
      PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
      TZ:   "${TZ}"
    command:
      - --meta_server_addrs="${SERVER1}":9559,${SERVER2}":9559,${SERVER3}":9559
      - --local_ip=storaged
      - --ws_ip=storaged
      - --port=9779
      - --ws_http_port=19779
      - --data_path=/data/storage
      - --log_dir=/logs
      - --v=0
      - --minloglevel=0
    depends_on:
      - metad
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:9779:9779
      - 0.0.0.0:19779:19779
      - 0.0.0.0:19780:19780
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sf", "http://storaged:19779/status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 20s
    volumes:
      - ./data/storage:/data/storage
      - ./logs/storage:/logs

  graphd:
    image: vesoft/nebula-graphd:v3.5.0
    environment:
      USER: "${USER}"
      PASSWORD: "${PASSWORD}"
      TZ:   "${TZ}"
    command:
      - --meta_server_addrs="${SERVER1}":9559,${SERVER2}":9559,${SERVER3}":9559
      - --port=9669
      - --local_ip=graphd
      - --ws_ip=graphd
      - --ws_http_port=19669
      - --log_dir=/logs
      - --v=0
      - --minloglevel=0
      - --enable_authorize=true
    depends_on:
      - storaged
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:5758:9669
      - 0.0.0.0:19669:19669
      - 0.0.0.0:19670:19670
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sf", "http://graphd:19669/status"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 20s
    volumes:
      - ./logs/graph:/logs

networks:
  nebula-net:
    external: true
```

but show error :

```
Log file created at: 2023/07/26 15:02:42
Running on machine: a3bbe51bcb1c
Running duration (h:mm:ss): 0:00:00
Log line format: [IWEF]yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
E20230726 15:02:42.507052     1 FileUtils.cpp:377] Failed to read the directory "/data/meta/nebula" (2): No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion about how running distribute to difference metal server in Nebula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple server containerized deployments, it's recommended to leverage NebulaGraph K8s Operator.

In case of the docker way, we could use swarm rather than the compose, refer to both the master branch and the swarm branch [here](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula-docker-compose/tree/docker-swarm) .

Regarding the meta data folder error, could you double check if it's already created automatically? For docker compose, it should be(for containerd I noticed it won't, but we could create on our own for once), thus the error should be OK as it's only reported in the initial run.

From your yaml, I can see the healthcheck lines are incorrect as they are calling the endpoint with domain name that's inside one container network `test: ["CMD", "curl", "-sf", "http://graphd:19669/status"]`, thus all services will be offline in this condition.

The final thing to be noted are, in the initial run, the storaged should be activated with the NeublaGraph Console to call `ADD HOSTS` with their exact SERVER IP and PORT in the configuration.

Hope this helps! and Welcome to the NebulaGraph community!

Comment: Nice, Thanks for this information. Yesterday, I wanted to have a personal chat with you on Twitter. But I felt hesitant.
I will try your suggestion. Thanks a lot

Comment: Dear Pamungkas, please don’t, feel free to dm me!